# Making folder and copying file

Tags: vb.net

I want my application to look for a file in drive C's specific folder (say C:\myFolder\abc.mdb), if found just give a message if not, make the folder in drive C:\ and then copy the file.

How to do this?
Thanks
Furqan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `File`, `Directory`, and `Path` objects in the `System.IO` as shown below:

```
Imports System.IO

...

Dim path As String = "C:\myFolder\abc.mdb"

If File.Exists(path) Then
     'TODO write code to create message'
Else
     Dim folder As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(path)
     If Not Directory.Exists(folder) then
         Directory.CreateDirectory(folder)
     End If
     'TODO code to copy file from current location to the newly created directory path'
     'i.e. File.Copy(FileToCopy, NewCopy)'
End If
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  FileCopy is the path where to get the file?

Comment: How to specify source path and target path?

Comment: FileToCopy is the full path to the already existing file that you would like to copy somewhere else. NewCopy would be the full path to of the new location of the copy. For example, `File.Copy("C:\abc.txt", C:\temp\abc.txt")`

Comment: Error: Directory not declared. any advise?

Comment: Try `System.IO.Directory`. A better way would be to get rid of the prefix, `System.IO`, and to put an `Import System.IO` at the top of the code. I've adjusted the code example to show this.

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is kind of old. I just wanted to update.
The quickest shortcut that will also create the Destination directory structure and in one line.  Use Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile instead of System.IO.

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(sSourcefile, sDestinationfile)
```