# VB.NET Copy multiple files on clipboard and paste with their folders

Tags: vb.net, file, copy, clipboard

I have a main folder "A" of program X, with files and sub folders "B" , "C" , "D" with files in them and other subfolders etc .
I have created a procedure that with some logic it populates some of those files with their full paths and a listview.

For example c:\A\B\File.txt etc

When the user checks files in the listview i copy the files to the clipboard with the following Sub

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        Dim DataObject As New DataObject
        Dim tempFileArray As New ArrayList
        For Each chkitem In ListView1.CheckedItems
            tempFileArray.Add(chkitem.text)
        Next

        DataObject.SetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, False, DirectCast(tempFileArray.ToArray(GetType(String)), String()))
        Clipboard.SetDataObject(DataObject)
    End Sub
```

At this time when the users does paste in a folder for example c:\OtherFolder , all the selected files are pasted inside c:\OtherFolder where the user pasted.

Is there any way when the user pastes in a folder the files, to be pasted with copies of their original paths ? I mean that if a file was copied from c:\A\B\File.txt then during the paste in C:\OtherFolder , a folder A and B to be created indide and the file.txt to be to be pasted inside folder C:\OtherFolder\A\B ?

Comment: What's the value of `chkitem.text` when you execute that code? Presumably it is just the name of the file. If you expect the drop target to be able to get the path out at the other end then you have to put that path in at your end.

Comment: @jmcilhinney , no its the whole path c:\A\B\File.txt

Comment: I'll do some testing and get back to you, if no one answers beforehand.

Comment: Why bother with the clipboard? Why not just ask the user where they want the files (save file dialog, or get them to drag the destination folder into your app) ?

Comment: @caius jard there is a specific reason why I use clipboard. The reason is that that it will be very often the need to be able to paste the files through RDP. I don't understand your thought although... What will be different if the user preselects the destination folder ?

Comment: Knowing the destination folder and the source allows you to append the source path onto the destination root

Comment: Copying files via clipboard/rdpclip is always a bit of a nuisance, I find; if I copy something else(eg text) while the transfer is ongoing it causes the file copy to abort.. That said I can't say I don't use it frequently regardless,so I understand the use case.I think if you're looking to retain that flexibility and be able to place files in a sub directory on the server you might need to run software at both ends; encode the path in the filename (turn c:\temp\mypath\file.mp3 into temp~mypath~file.mp3 and then a software with a filesystemwatcher on the server side can rename/re-path the file?

Comment: The reall need is very clause to what you're guessing but your idea is not applicable in my specific case because its not server and client everytime. It could be any computer to any computer . You gave me a clue althought. If i have a predefinded temp folder then with sth like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127107/making-folder-and-copying-file  in a temp and then secondly and silently  loop a copy for all the contents of the temp folder (folders and files) i think i solved my problem. At least if by hand i was doing this then i would get the result i am searching for in the clipbr